# How to use context bound to a class

Tags: scala

I have a value and context bound to its type in a case class. In a function, I want to use this case class and its contained value in the bound context.

Example:

```
object Example {
  trait ObjectLike[A] {
    def properties(a: A): Map[String, Any]
  }

  case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

  object Person {
    implicit val personObjectLike = new ObjectLike[Person] {
      override def properties(a: Person): Map[String, Any] = Map(
        "name" -> a.name,
        "age" -> a.age
      )
    }
  }

  case class Company(name: String, founded: Int)
  object Company {
    implicit val companyObjectLike = new ObjectLike[Company] {
      override def properties(a: Company): Map[String, Any] = Map(
        "name" -> a.name,
        "founded" -> a.founded
      )
    }
  }

  // I have the case class with the context bound here.
  case class ObjectStore[Obj : ObjectLike](objs: List[Obj])

  // Here is the function where I want to use it
  def getNames[A](store: ObjectStore[A]): List[String] = {
    store.objs
      .map((a) => {
        implicitly[ObjectLike[A]].properties(a).get("name").map(_.toString)
      })
      .flatten
  }
}
```

This doesn't compile however. The error message is

```
Error:(32, 19) could not find implicit value for parameter e: Example.ObjectLike[A]
        implicitly[ObjectLike[A]].properties(a).get("name").map(_.toString)

Error:(32, 19) not enough arguments for method implicitly: (implicit e: Example.ObjectLike[A])Example.ObjectLike[A].
Unspecified value parameter e.
        implicitly[ObjectLike[A]].properties(a).get("name").map(_.toString)
```

Note that I don't want to alter the signature of `getNames` with an implicit evidence, I want to somehow summon it from the class, as it should already be there I think.

Comment: How would you summon it from the class without adding an implicit evidence for it? You don't know what the class is, it's a generic type parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can expose the evidence through a method in `ObjectStore`.

```
case class ObjectStore[Obj : ObjectLike](objs: List[Obj]) {
  def evidence = implicitly[ObjectLike[Obj]]
}
```

Then you can use `store.evidence` to access it.